# Android recovery tools (4EXT, etc)

Tags: android, recovery

I wanted to know if the recovery tools like 4EXT are secure to install.
Do they 'act' only when booting in recovery mode or also they can control system when using phone normally?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

4EXT and others are only enhanced versions of the stock Android recovery system. They do not interact with the system unless you are in recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!
another thing... I installed 4EXT and then unroot the system. Could this influence any functionality of the system?

Comment: It does not seem to me that one third party is in a position to reliably tell you what another piece of third party code does or does not do, unless you can be sure that they have reviewed the exact build you contemplate installing, or source that you or a trusted agent built from with trusted tools.  As for influencing functionality, breaking acceptance of an official update would be a likely example (though avoiding an undesired one might be viewed as a good thing by some).  But one would not expect the recovery system to be involved in ordinary operation of the device.